# WEB-INF content access in another war

Tags: java, deployment, jsp-tags

I have three war files (War-Common, War-Physical, War-Derivatives) and we are packaging them in an EAR file. I am able to access content (Images, CSS, JavaScripts etc.) of War-Common in War-Physical and War-Derivatives but I am not able to access content of WEB-INF folder of War-Common War. We are acutally placing jsp custom tags inside it but I am not able to access them.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/test.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WEB-INF/tags/Calendar.tag"></script>
```

But I am not able to use Calendar.tag.

Its not only tags that cannot be accessed, I am not able to access jsp from WEB-INF folder in  War-Physical and War-Derivatives. I guess you cannot access content of WEB-INF in other war files.

Comment: How are you accessing the tag from your client JSP?

Comment: Include <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/eka.tld" prefix="eka"%> in the jsp file and using <eka:Calendar name="shipmentDetailForm" property="activityDate" size="12" /> Same code works if I use this in War-Common War.

Comment: Referring to a JSP tagfile from an HTML `<script>` element doesn't make any sense. I can't even figure out what that's supposed to do.

Comment: its my mistake, we don't need <script> tag for using JSP custom tags..but its not only about tags, I am not even able to aceess jsp files from WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems its not possible to access web-inf content from one war to another war..so closing this question..

Answer (score 0):

You can put your static files (images/css/javascript etc.) in one core-war(with root context or any other other context). You can then access them easily.